# using html and css: <select> <option> Nigeria </option> </select> so how do i insert country / region above nigeria

Tags: html, css

[image]

```
<select> <option> Nigeria </option> </select>
```

how do i insert country / region above nigeria inside the box

Answer (score 0):

You can just add another `option` tag like this:

```html
<select>
  <option>North pole</option>
  <option>Nigeria</option>
</select>
```

Make sure to check out the details here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select